# Get the source of a Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to get the source of a template. I looked into [the template APIs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#module-django.template.loader) and into the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fe995e6cbdcf2766cf0aa951c8ef4549ad27694c/django/template/loader.py#L118) with no success.

Apparently, the Template object [keeps no reference](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fe995e6cbdcf2766cf0aa951c8ef4549ad27694c/django/template/base.py#L123) to the original source.

Before messing up my codebase I'm asking: is there a simple way to get the source of a template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Template` objects don't keep a reference to the original source, but they *do* keep a reference to the original *source file* and you can re-read the source from there:

```
source = open(template_instance.origin.name, 'r').read()
```

Comment: That's great, but I've just noticed that in Django 1.6 this is not implemented: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/template/base.py

Comment: Indeed; this issue seems to be [fixed in the 1.7 branch](https://github.com/django/django/commit/8625c7aab3760d16572792fea23a95e572e28ead). I've been testing this on an existing project of mine, where it turns out to be [monkey-patched by the `django-debug-toolbar` module](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/blob/master/debug_toolbar/panels/templates/panel.py#L70). You might consider following the same approach.

Comment: Be aware that template.origin does not exist with TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False on Django 1.7 - it will work great in your development environment and then fail miserably on staging or worse production.

Answer (score 2):

If you know exactly what loader is loading template you can use Loader method directly.

```
from django.template.loaders.app_directories import Loader
source = Loader.load_template_source(file_name)[0]
```

file_name is same as when loading templates with loader.get_template(file_name)

Answer (score 0):

There is a great shortcut called [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut).

As de docs says:

> It loads a template, renders it and returns the resulting string:

`from django.template.loader import render_to_string
rendered = render_to_string('my_template.html', {'foo': 'bar'})`

So, the variable rendered is a string with the source code of the template

Comment: `rendered` will end up with the _rendered_ (duh) template, not its _source_ (as it is in the template file on disk).

Answer (score -2):

Templates are text files (usually, HTML, but not necessarily) that get rendered with a context (usually) when called from a call to, for instance, [django.shortcuts.render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render). If you have a view function, that should specify which template it's using.

From the docs:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {"foo": "bar"},
        content_type="application/xhtml+xml")
```

Here, the template would be *"templates/myapp/index.html"*.

Comment: This does not answer the question.